# Cannot read property 'url' of undefined in Strapi with nuxt,js

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, nuxt.js, strapi

I get Cannot read property 'url' of undefined error.
I don't understand why.
When i change line
`<img :src="'api.example.com' + gallery.Main_picture.url">`
to for example `{{ gallery.Title }}`  everything work as it should. what i'm doing wrong?
In console i see whole response as it should look. I will be grateful for any help and thank you in advance. I changed my api domain for example.com

```
<template>
  <v-row no-gutters class="black--text">
    <v-col>
      <img :src="'api.example.com' + gallery.Main_picture.url">
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      gallery: {}
    }
  },
  async mounted () {
    this.gallery = await this.$strapi.$galleries.findOne(this.$route.params.id)
    console.log(this.gallery.Main_picture.url)
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
<img :src="`//api.example.com${gallery.Main_picture.url}`">
```